# Win8 Store app: How to make popup ui call in sync way in bg render thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, monogame

I can't understand how can I implement sync MessageBox/QueryBox/QueryStringBox calls in my Monogame Windows Store application.

In realizations of our engine on other platforms (Android, WP7/8, IOS) we call MessageBox/QueryBox/QueryStringBox wrapper in sync way:

```
if (SysDlg.QRESULT_YES == SysDlg.showQueryBox(APP_NAME, "Save data?", S_YES, S_NO))
{
    //Save data
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

It's the most convenient way, as gui code becomes linear. Such calls are made inside a background render thread, so it's ok if we wait inside SysDlg.showQueryBox. Pseudocode looks like this:

```
    int standardOpenDlg(int dlgType, <some arguments>)
{
    msDlgActive = true;

    < async construct and show dlg on main UI thread with handler like below >
    dlg.onButtonPress += () => 
    { 
        dlg.close(); 
        msDlgResult = 1; 
        msDlgActive = false; 
    }

    while (msDlgActive)
        EngineSystem.Sleep(100);

    //when user presses button msDlgActive becomes false and we quit endless loop and return msDlgResult

    return msDlgResult;
}
```

In my current case I have such MessageBox code:

```
var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(msDlgText, msDlgTitle);
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(buttonsTexts[i], 
        new UICommandInvokedHandler(MsgBoxInputFinishedCallBack), (int)i));
messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

And buttons' callback:

```
private static void MsgBoxInputFinishedCallBack(IUICommand command)
{
    // get the result           
    if (command != null && command.Id != null)
    {
        int result = (int)command.Id;
        msDlgResult = (int)result;
    }
    msDlgActive = false;
}
```

I've tried to wrap messagebox creation and call in

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, ()  => {...} );
```

But if I block my background draw thread after that I never see the message box. It looks like MainGame.Update (it executes exactly in this bg thread) should finish and return control to the system so that my code on main thread can be executed.

If I call (even in my thread) and then continue execution (but also leave caller context without msDlgResult ) I messagebox appears as expected.

I also tried

```
messageDialog.ShowAsync();

await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

Task t = messageDialog.ShowAsync().AsTask();
t.Wait();
```

but nothing helps.

In Windows Phone 8 I just called Guide.BeginShowMessageBox with callback and everything worked fine.

I suppose I don't quite understand this new Metro and async/await (although I know what is it).
Please tell how can I wait in bg thread until messagebox closed? 
Maybe I should use some other winRT UI for that?
Thanks!

------Update

If anybody cares - finally I had to create/show dialogbox and handle results in two different places.

Comment: You can't really have a "Background Draw Thread". If your app is drawing something, it is on the *one* UI thread. If it is preparing something to draw (such as doing calculations for new coordinates), then it is possible to do that, but it is not actually drawing. What you can do is create an `async` event handler for the button which disables the button, awaits the message box return, then responds. This should run on the UI thread what it needs without blocking the UI thread. Calling `t.Wait()` synchronously blocks the UI thread.

Comment: It is XNA (Monogame) application (XAML is used only for main window wrapper). I see in debug that there are many threads, one of them is  my Draw-Update thread. And when I block my thread UI thread still works and windows doesn't try to close my aplication. Am I miss something? On other platforms the same architecture is used. UI thread for UI, and draw thread updating OpenGL/DirectX surface.

Comment: Windows won't try to close your application if the UI thread is blocked, it just will 'lock up' (not update the UI) while the processing is being done. You'll note you mentioned that if you block the draw thread, it blocks your 'main thread'. This is because the 'main thread' is the UI thread. All of the actual UI updates are being marshalled to that thread. If it has locked the main thread, then it will block your other code from running. This is why you should use `async/await`, as it won't block the UI thread while doing the background processing.

Comment: So, the answer to the question: "how can I wait in bg thread until messagebox closed?" is "Make the method you are calling `async` then `await` the `ShowAsync` method."

Comment: Yes, I'll implement it via sync/await if I will not find a sync way. But you don't get the point. I said that blocking bg thread prevents my   code, sent to dispatcher, to be executed. But as far as I understand UI thread runs properly. I suppose you wrote multithread apps. How can blocking bg thread stop main thread? In debug->threads (in VS2012) I see main UI thread and also see that my code is executed in bg thread. But maybe monogame somehow syncronizes its working thread with main behind the scenes... So my question is still unanswered.

Comment: If the BG thread is prepping content and sending it to the UI thread, then it's probably marshalling content to the UI thread. To do this, it gets a lock on the UI thread. If it doesn't ever give up that lock, then it's a deadlock. At the very least, that's how it can be blocking the UI thread.

Comment: It makes sense. But when I call messageDialog.ShowAsync() it does the same? I mean it marshalls this popup under the hood anyway (and blocks UI thread)?

Comment: If you call messageDialog.ShowAsync(), it should not block. What it does is returns a Task. If you call `Wait` on this `Task`, it blocks the thread until the task returns. If you had multiple tasks running on the same thread, you could `await` both of them without blocking the thread (via `Task.WhenAll` or `Task.WhenAny`). Now, it's possible that the MessageDialog class blocks the UI thread on its own. In which case, you may have to make your own solution. Maybe try with a simple test app. Throw up a dialog on button click (`async`/`await`), then draw stuff in the background.